# Error in mule start up due to long properties file

Tags: mule, mule-studio, properties-file

I am facing one weird issue while running mule application. We have multiple entries in mule-app.properties (220 lines
). When I try to run the application, it fails with `file or extension too` error.

[image]

When I remove some random entries from properties file, application starts successfully. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had a similar issue to this, and it because of the way the entries in mule-app.properties are applied at runtime. The JVM is complaining that the VM arguments are too long, which is how properties in mule-app.properties are applied.

The way you can work-around it is to store your properties in a separate `.properties` file in `src/main/resources` and include this file as a property placeholder in your global configuration:

`<context:property-placeholder location="myApp.properties"/>`

Note if you use environment specific properties like this also you can reference multiple files separated with a comma, e.g.

`<context:property-placeholder location="myApp.properties, ${mule.environment}.properties" />`

Comment: Already did this. It works fine if run with standalone mule application. Anyways thanks for your answer.